# Programmatically assign VBA code to MouseupEvent in access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created form dynamically in VBA. The below query will create the form with MouseupEvent.But it doesnt contain any code inside the event. I want to know how to insert VBA code for this particular event. Do we need to use any Modules or Functions ??

```
Set frm = CreateForm()
frm.AllowAdditions = False      
frm.AllowDeletions = False
frm.AllowEdits = False
frm.OnMouseUp = "[Event Procedure]"
```

Waiting for your valuable response...

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of consists of the following steps:

- Create a public function in a Module
  [image: new module]

Note that this is a separate module, not one of the form modules.
Also it has to be **PUBLIC**, and it has to be a **FUNCTION**.

- Create a new macro for : RunCode - FunctionName
  [image: create macro]

When adding the function to the runCode arguments, do it through the expression builder to make sure it can be accessed.

- `frm.OnMouseUp = "MacroName"`

I have tested with the following code :

[image: sample code]

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created Macro using Runcode. frm.OnMouseUp = "Macro1" In action arguments I have given my function name frmMouseup(). This function is available in module, it contains VBA code for Mouseup event. But when i try to click on the columns headrs, i am getting the error message like, "The expression you entered has a function name that MS access can't find".Kindly let me know, where i have made the mistake.

Comment: I have added some pictures for you to look over the steps. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much MR.parakmiakos. Past three days its making me uncomfortable. Now my problem has been solved.  Thanks a lot. You are the access expert. :) :)

Comment: Accepting the answer would be largely appreciated :D